# How to classify geometric shape of logo images (32x32)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, conv-neural-network, feature-extraction

I'm currently working on classifying geometric shapes (circle, triangle, rectangle, square, pentagon) of logo images with 32x32 pixels.

I've tried training CNN to classify geometric shape but the accuracy is low. I also have tried using OpenCV library but the logo images doesn't have clear geometric shape and sometimes with text as well. Is there any software or algorithm that can solve this classification problem?

Here is my sample logo images: https://ibb.co/album/nBMf1F
I want to classify logo images into geometric shape categories such as circle, triangle, square, and etc.

Comment: Your question is too broad for this forum. Please post code and your input and output results and ask a question pertinent to your issue. You can upload images to some free hosting service and put the URLs. Please read this forum's help section about how to ask a good question.

Comment: You may want to extract first the contours inside your images and then you can perform mactch shape tests (to find out the most probable geometry). This can be done with OpenCV. If the geometry is not well defined, you can try preprocess the image with morphological transformations, thresholding and filters